# How to display the one UL box inside another Ul box along with text in the center?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have below design which I am trying to create using HTML and CSS.
Each box has a text inside. I thought I can do this using `ul li` but it's very difficult for me to create.

I tried the below code but I'm a little bit confused that my code is the best code or is there any other easy way to handle this?

Also, how do I display my one `ul` box inside another?

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.first {
  width: 400px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(1) {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}

ul.two {
  width: 600px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(1) {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(2) {
  top: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(6) {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(7) {
  bottom: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(8) {
  top: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="innerHero"><a href="">I am hero</a></div>

  <ul class="first">
    <li><a href="">Test one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test four</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="two">
    <li><a href="">Example one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example four</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example five</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example six</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example eight</a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: With regard to the suggestions about list nesting below, your list structure should reflect the nature of the information for good document semantics and accessibility. Lists shouldn't be used to arbitrarily position content on the page. If you find yourself violating that principle, just use divs or other layout elements.

Comment: @isherwood, Actually, I thought UL LI is a good way to do. So I have to use div instated of ul li. right?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your `ul` elements as you wish. Just create another `ul` element inside `li` element.

```css
        .wrapper {
            width: 700px;
            margin: auto;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }

        ul li {
            border: 1px solid #f00;
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
        }

        ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul.first {
            width: 600px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        ul.first li:nth-child(1) {
            top: -10px;
            left: 30px;
        }

        ul.first li:nth-child(2) {
            top: 30px;
            right: -30px;
        }

        ul.first li:nth-child(3) {
            bottom: -10px;
            right: 30px;
        }

        ul.first li:nth-child(4) {
            bottom: 30px;
            left: -30px;
        }

        ul.two {
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(1) {
            top: -10px;
            left: 30px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(2) {
            top: -10px;
            right: 30px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(3) {
            top: 30px;
            right: -30px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(4) {
            bottom: 30px;
            right: -30px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(5) {
            bottom: -10px;
            right: 30px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(6) {
            bottom: -10px;
            left: 30px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(7) {
            bottom: 30px;
            left: -30px;
        }

        ul.two li:nth-child(8) {
            top: 30px;
            left: -30px;
        }
```

```html
<ul class="first">
        <li><a href="">Test one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test four</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul class="two">
                <li><a href="">Example one</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example two</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example three</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example four</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example five</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example six</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example seven</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example eight</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `position` of the container to `relative` and alter all of inner contents' `position` to `absolute` will make them all their position depend to its container whereas how you want you can adjust every element by altering its `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` till you get an expected output

When you done you will possibly face with another problem which is that

> you won't click on the links that are inside the content you placed inside another

you know why that problem will happen is because the top elements is probably overlapping your `divs` but don't worry I got the solution too just apply a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) this will prevent the inner `divs` to being overlapped here is thing

> when one div is inside another you can simply set `z-index` to `1` and when there is another clickable elements which is located inside the `div` which has `z-index` you will increase the `z-index` of that `div` so that will be `z-index: 2;` this will prevent it from being overlapped by the `div` which has `z-index` to.

### Example

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

ul.first {
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.two {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(1) {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(1) {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(2) {
  top: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(6) {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(7) {
  bottom: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(8) {
  top: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}

.innerHero {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 55%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="innerHero"><a href="">I am hero</a></div>

  <ul class="first">
    <li><a href="">Test one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test four</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="two">
    <li><a href="">Example one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example four</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example five</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example six</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example eight</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: My expected output is different as per your snippet.

Comment: @user9437856 did my solution not meet with you expected output if yes where do you need me to improve, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems to me that you don't really mean nesting the lists as a main and sublist *semantically* in HTML, but just position one "list box" inside the other (layoutwise).

Based on that, in my answer I applied `position: absolute;` to the smaller of the two "list boxes", together with some parameters for its position and size (top/left/width/height). For the `position: absolute;` to work as intended, it's necessary to add `position: relative` to the parent of the two boxes, the `.wrapper` div.

Also the hero text can be placed in a similar way, using `position: absolute` and the settings shown below, since it is a sibling of the two "list boxes". That way both the smaller "list box" and the hero div's positions are anchored to the position of the wrapper, but *outside* the document flow (due to the absolute position), that way not taking any space of their own, but overlapping the larger "list box".

Edit: I added `z-index` properties for the inner box and the hero text link to make the included links clickable.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

ul.first {
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index:1;
}

ul.two {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
.innerHero {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index:2;
}
ul li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(1) {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.first li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(1) {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(2) {
  top: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(6) {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(7) {
  bottom: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}

ul.two li:nth-child(8) {
  top: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="innerHero"><a href="">I am hero</a></div>

  <ul class="first">
    <li><a href="">Test one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test four</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="two">
    <li><a href="">Example one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example four</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example five</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example six</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Example eight</a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to click on Test one, Test two and so on.

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot about that. I additionally added z-indexes for the inner box and the hero text link now to make the included links clickable.